# Select only month and year in Calendar Datepicker issue

Tags: magento, datepicker

Is there a way to get something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7755/) in magento calendar ?

This is my code:

```
Calendar.setup({
        inputField: "myfield",
        ifFormat: "%m/%e/%Y",
        showsTime: false,
        button: "_myfield_date_trig",
        align: "Bl",
        singleClick : true,
        disableFunc: function(date) {
                 // show only month and year 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149392/how-do-i-create-date-input-field-with-calendar-in-magneto2-solved) and apply css to hide the ui calendar

```
<div class="control customer-dob">
<input type="text"
       class="input-text required-entry hasDatepicker"
       id="calendar_inputField"
       name="calendar_inputField"
       aria-required="true" />
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function ($) {
        $("#calendar_inputField").calendar({
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM/yy',
            yearRange: "2017:2050",
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```